# Problem with app sending email followed by two empty emails

Tags: c#, asp.net, email

My app is sending 3 emails at the same time to the recipient, one being the correct email, and the other two contain the subject line, but an empty message. Could this code some how cause that? If not what do you suggest?

```
 var fromAddress = new MailAddress(domainAddress, displayName);
        var toAddress = new MailAddress(oInfo.SiteUser.email, oInfo.customerName);
        var Bcc = new MailAddress("deleted");
        var smtp = new SmtpClient
        {
            Host = SmtpHost(),
            Port = SmtpPort(),
            EnableSsl = true,

            DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network,
            UseDefaultCredentials = false,
            Credentials = new NetworkCredential(SmtpUsername(), SmtpPassword())
        };

using (var msg = new MailMessage(fromAddress, toAddress)
        {
            IsBodyHtml = true,
            Subject = "Confirmation for your recent order at " + displayName,
            Body = body

        })
        {
            msg.Bcc.Add(Bcc);
            smtp.Send(msg);
        }
```

Comment: Is it intermittent or do 3 emails consistently go out for every 1 that you intend?

Comment: The code looks OK, time to look in the logfile(s) and esp the headers in the received mails.

Comment: Another option would be to look at the method that calls this one where you are generating the e-mails. Perhaps you are calling it more than once & sending the wrong body text on the subsequent calls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, that code won't send more than one mail.

Either you have some more code that is sending mail, or you are executing that code three times, but with different values for body.

Answer (score 0):

The only problem I can see with that code is the line

```
    var Bcc = new MailAddress("deleted");
```

but I assume you modified it for posting here?

I can't see an issue that would cause what you're seeing.  I'd check the headers in the emails for clues.  Also capturing network traffic on the machine sending the emails could help.